# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 : 10.1 - Can't pick up "Enter"

Tags: android, keyboard, keylistener

Ok, so this is silly.
I am using a textbox with the input type textPassword.

On the Galaxy Tab 2 : 10.1 : I can not pick up the "Done" button as in an arrow pointing down then turning left.

I am doing the following check:

```
tv2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        performRegister();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The above code works correctly on 95% of devices that I have tried it is only the Galaxy Tab that is giving me this issue.
I have also tried :

```
tv2.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            //CODE!!
        }
    });
```

But neither of these methods get called when I press the button. (Not called at all! It's not that I am not checking for the correct KeyEvent: There is no KeyEvent)

All that this button does is to hide the Keyboard.

Ps. I am using the Galaxy tab with the Samsung Chinese IME keyboard. v2.0.3

Thanks for any help:
Aiden

Comment: How did you solved this problem? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Comment: matts option looks nice, but in my case, the imeOption is defined on the xml file, so I don't need to redefine it again under the activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
TextView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

then you should get a callback in your OnEditorActionListener